# How to multiline radio controls on dialog using MFC

Tags: mfc, dialog, radio-button, multiline

I have three radio options on my dialog:

[image]

Is it possible to turn these radio options in to multiline?

Ignore the other controls that seem to overlap because they are only visible correctly at run time.

It is just the three radio options I would like to word wrap if possible.

This is on MFC Dialog.

Comment: I really wonder that _you_ didn't know this already. It's a well asked question anyway.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I used radio controls for some 20 years. I knew they could be changed to look like buttons but I never realised they could be multiline out of the box. I was overcomplicating it in my head that I did not see the basic solution staring me in the face! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Is it possible to turn these radio options in to multiline?*

Yes! If you are using the resource editor, then select the radio-button in question and, in the "Properties" pane, set the "Multiline" condition (in the "Appearance" group) to **True**.

If you are editing the resource script manually, then add the `BS_MULTILINE` style to the control.

The following screenshot is from Visual Studio 2010, but the UI is very similar in VS 2019, IIRC:

[image]

And here is the resource script, for the above dialog box, showing the use of the `BS_MULTILINE` style:

```
IDD_ABOUTBOX DIALOGEX 0, 0, 258, 132
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "About AppWizDog"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 0, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    ICON            IDR_MAINFRAME, IDC_STATIC, 14,14,20,20
    LTEXT           "AppWizDog, Version 1.0",IDC_STATIC, 42,14,114,8, SS_NOPREFIX
    LTEXT           "Copyright (C) 2014", IDC_STATIC, 42,26,114,8
    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "OK", IDOK, 201,111,50,14, WS_GROUP
    CONTROL         "This is a long caption text", IDC_RADIO1, "Button",
                     BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON | BS_MULTILINE, 7,52,62,22
END
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Once I have opportunity to get on my computer I will try and then hit the accept button. :)